# TFS - What security would allow me to 'Add files' in one project and not the other?

Tags: tfs

In TFS Source Control Explorer, in some projects the "New Folder" and "Add Files" icons are visibles, and for other projects they are not.  I'm a contributor in both, and I can check in solutions in both, and not an admin for either.

What could possibly be making the icons go "dim".  Is it security?  Or some other combination of rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you have that folder mapped in your current workspace.  If it isn't mapped, you wont' be able to add files.  Based on you saying that you can't even click on the Add Files button, that makes me think this is the issue.

If that's not the case, and you need to drill down into security, I highly recommend the free Team Foundation Sidekicks from Attrice, which you can find at http://www.attrice.info/

Look at their "Permissions Sidekick" within the tool.

Comment: Thanks, this relates to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916736/tfs-disk-structure-and-add-new-folder-vs-add-solution/2936676#2936676.  I guess the workspace is not created until you check-in something, so do add a whole directory of files, you have to setup the workspace first.

Comment: You'll want to set up a workspace and map the directory before you do anything.  We use a methodology where we have (among others) a MAIN and DEV branch for each of our team projects.  Originally, we used one workspace for MAIN and another for DEV.  Ultimately, we switched to simply using a workspace called "WorkLocal" that maps "$/" to a local directory.  That way we can easily work between branches.